# Status code was: 1 Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited

Tags: django, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i was using selenium , chrmoedriver to make screen short of the provided url in my django app.

```
def take_url_screenshot(url):
    # Ensure the "screenshot" folder exists or create it if not available
    screenshot_folder = "screenshot"
    if not os.path.exists(f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/{screenshot_folder}"):
        print(f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/{screenshot_folder}")
        os.makedirs(f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/{screenshot_folder}")
    # Create Chrome options
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    # Create an instance of Chrome webdriver with the headless option
    service = ChromiumService(executable_path=r"/usr/bin/chromedriver")

    driver = webdriver.ChromiumEdge(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    # Take a screenshot and save it in the "screenshot" folder
    image_name = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", url)
    screenshot_path = os.path.join(
        f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/{screenshot_folder}/{image_name}.png"
    )
    driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()

    return f"{screenshot_folder}/{image_name}.png"
```

this is working fine in localhost, but when i deployed my django application this make exception : Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

version details:
os :               ubuntu 22.04
chromium-browser : 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
chromedriver:      ChromeDriver 122.0.6261.128
selenium:          4.12.0

i have checked ./chromedriver which is returning:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 122.0.6261.128 (f18a44fedeb29764b2b5336c120fdd90ef1a3f5c-refs/branch-heads/6261@{#1057}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

i have tried in my localhost which is working fine. but the problem comes from the server